# routing core smart sql functions

Tags: pgrouting

I found routing core smart file [here](https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting-contrib/blob/master/functions-v1.x/routing_core_smart.sql) but unfortunately is for version 1 of pgrouting...
and when i want to use it in pgrouting v2 i get a lot of errors ( because of functions that have been changed in postgis v2 eg. getsrid->st_srid)
Is there any compatible smart functions for pgrouting v2??

Comment: No, there isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so i had to convert it to V2 compatible, by my self. 
here it is:

```
CREATE TYPE link_point AS (id integer, name varchar);
CREATE TYPE links AS (f geometry, l geometry);

CREATE TYPE edge AS ( gid integer,
             target       integer,
             source       integer,
             x1           double precision,
             y1           double precision,
             x2           double precision, 
             y2           double precision, 
             length       double precision, 
             reverse_cost double precision, 
--           id           integer,
--           class_id     smallint,
             to_cost      double precision,
             rule         text,
             the_geom     geometry );

CREATE TYPE edge_array AS ( gid integer[6],
             target       integer[6],
             source       integer[6],
             x1           double precision[6],
             y1           double precision[6],
             x2           double precision[6], 
             y2           double precision[6], 
             length       double precision[6], 
             reverse_cost double precision[6], 
--           id           integer[6],
--           class_id     smallint[6],
             to_cost      double precision[6],
             rule         text[6],
             the_geom     geometry[6] );


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_network_info(src varchar) RETURNS void AS
$$
DECLARE
  m_gid integer;
  m_v_id integer;
  longest_l double precision;
  l_num integer;  

  r record;
  ex boolean;

BEGIN
  FOR r IN EXECUTE 'SELECT  count(*) as l_num, max(st_length(the_geom)) as longest_l, max(gid) AS max_gid, '''||src||''' as tname, greatest(max(source), max(target)) AS max_vertex_id FROM '||src
  LOOP
  END LOOP;

  m_gid := r.max_gid;
  m_v_id := r.max_vertex_id;
  longest_l := r.longest_l;
  l_num := r.l_num;

  select (select relname from pg_class where relname='network_info') is null INTO ex;

  IF ex THEN
  CREATE TABLE network_info(tname text, max_gid integer, max_vertex_id integer, longest_link_length double precision, link_num integer);
  END IF;

  EXECUTE 'DELETE FROM network_info where tname='''||src||'''';
  INSERT INTO network_info VALUES(src, m_gid, m_v_id, longest_l, l_num);
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

-------------------------------------------------------------------
-- This function finds nearest link to a given node
-- point - text representation of point
-- distance - function will search for a link within this distance
-- tbl - table name
-------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_nearest_link_within_distance(point varchar, 
    distance double precision, tbl varchar)
    RETURNS INT AS
$$
DECLARE
    row record;
    x float8;
    y float8;

    srid integer;

BEGIN
    FOR row IN EXECUTE 'select st_srid(the_geom) as srid from '||tbl||' where gid = (select min(gid) from '||tbl||')' LOOP
    END LOOP;
    srid:= row.srid;

    -- Getting x and y of the point

    FOR row in EXECUTE 'select st_x(st_GeometryFromText('''||point||''', '||srid||')) as x' LOOP
    END LOOP;
    x:=row.x;

    FOR row in EXECUTE 'select st_y(st_GeometryFromText('''||point||''', '||srid||')) as y' LOOP
    END LOOP;
    y:=row.y;

    -- Searching for a link within the distance

    FOR row in EXECUTE 'select gid, ST_distance(the_geom, st_GeometryFromText('''||point||''', '||srid||')) as dist from '||tbl||
                ' where ST_SetSRID(''BOX3D('||x-distance||' '||y-distance||', '||x+distance||' '||y+distance||')''::BOX3D, '||srid||')&&the_geom order by dist asc limit 1'
    LOOP
    END LOOP;

    IF row.gid IS NULL THEN
        --RAISE EXCEPTION 'Data cannot be matched';
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;

    RETURN row.gid;

END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE STRICT;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_nearest_link_within_distance_xy(x double precision, 
    y double precision, distance double precision, tbl varchar)
    RETURNS INT AS
$$
DECLARE
    row record;

    srid integer;

BEGIN

    FOR row IN EXECUTE 'select st_srid(the_geom) as srid from '||tbl||' where gid = (select min(gid) from '||tbl||')' LOOP
    END LOOP;
    srid:= row.srid;

    -- Searching for a link within the distance

    FOR row in EXECUTE 'select gid, ST_distance(the_geom, ST_GeometryFromText(''POINT('||x||' '||y||')'', '||srid||')) as dist from '||tbl||
                ' where ST_SetSRID(''BOX3D('||x-distance||' '||y-distance||', '||x+distance||' '||y+distance||')''::BOX3D, '||srid||')&&the_geom order by dist asc limit 1'
    LOOP
    END LOOP;

    IF row.gid IS NULL THEN
        --RAISE EXCEPTION 'Data cannot be matched';
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;

    RETURN row.gid;

END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE STRICT;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION locate_point_as_geometry(tbl varchar, edge integer, px double precision, py double precision, col boolean)
    RETURNS LINKS AS
$$
DECLARE
    row record;
    num integer;
    i integer;
    geom geoms;

    l links;
    pos double precision;

    srid integer;

BEGIN

    FOR row IN EXECUTE 'select ST_srid(the_geom) as srid from '||tbl||' where gid = (select min(gid) from '||tbl||')' LOOP
    END LOOP;
    srid:= row.srid;

--    RAISE NOTICE 'select * from line_locate_point((select linemerge(the_geom) from % where gid=%), ST_geometryfromtext(''POINT(% %)'', %)) as pos', tbl, edge, px, py, srid;

    FOR row in EXECUTE 'select distinct * from ST_line_locate_point((select distinct ST_linemerge(the_geom) from '||tbl||' where gid='||edge||'), ST_geometryfromtext(''POINT('
                ||px||' '||py||')'', '||srid||')) as pos'
    LOOP
    END LOOP;

    pos:=row.pos;

    -- Creating new geometries

    FOR row in EXECUTE 'select distinct * from ST_line_substring((select distinct ST_linemerge(the_geom) from '||tbl||' where gid='||edge||'), 0, '||pos||') as link'
    LOOP
    END LOOP;

    l.f:=row.link;
    IF ST_geometrytype(l.f) = 'POINT' THEN
      --RAISE NOTICE 'POINT >>> %', astext(l.f);
      l.f := ST_geometryfromtext('LINESTRING('||x(l.f)||' '||y(l.f)||','||x(l.f)||' '||y(l.f)||')');
    END IF;

    IF col THEN l.f = st_collect(l.f);
    END IF;


    FOR row in EXECUTE 'select distinct * from ST_line_substring((select distinct ST_linemerge(the_geom) from '||tbl||' where gid='||edge||'), '||pos||', 1) as link'
    LOOP
    END LOOP;

    l.l:=row.link;
    IF ST_geometrytype(l.l) = 'POINT' THEN
      --RAISE NOTICE 'POINT >>> %', astext(l.l);
      l.l := ST_geometryfromtext('LINESTRING('||x(l.l) ||' '||y(l.l)||','||x(l.l)||' '||y(l.l)||')');
    END IF;

    IF col THEN l.l = ST_collect(l.l);
    END IF;

    RETURN l;

END;
$$

LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE STRICT;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_middle(tbl varchar, edge integer, px1 double precision, py1 double precision, px2 double precision, py2 double precision, col boolean)
    RETURNS GEOMETRY AS
$$
DECLARE
    row record;
    num integer;
    i integer;
    geom geoms;

    l geometry;
    pos1 double precision;
    pos2 double precision;

    srid integer;
    query text;

BEGIN

    FOR row IN EXECUTE 'select st_srid(the_geom) as srid from '||tbl||' where gid = (select min(gid) from '||tbl||')' LOOP
    END LOOP;
    srid:= row.srid;

--    RAISE NOTICE 'select * from line_locate_point((select ST_linemerge(the_geom) from % where gid=%), ST_geometryfromtext(''POINT(% %)'', %)) as pos', tbl, edge, px, py, srid;

    FOR row in EXECUTE 'select distinct * from ST_line_locate_point((select distinct ST_linemerge(the_geom) from '||tbl||' where gid='||edge||'), ST_geometryfromtext(''POINT('
                ||px1||' '||py1||')'', '||srid||')) as pos'
    LOOP
    END LOOP;   
    pos1:=row.pos;

    FOR row in EXECUTE 'select distinct * from ST_line_locate_point((select distinct ST_linemerge(the_geom) from '||tbl||' where gid='||edge||'), ST_geometryfromtext(''POINT('
                ||px2||' '||py2||')'', '||srid||')) as pos'
    LOOP
    END LOOP;   
    pos2:=row.pos;

    query := 'select ST_line_substring((select distinct ST_linemerge(the_geom) from '||tbl||' where gid='||edge||'), ';

    IF pos1 < pos2 THEN query:= query||pos1||', '||pos2;
    ELSE query:= query || pos2||', '||pos1;
    END IF;

    query := query ||') as link';

    -- Creating new geomety

    FOR row in EXECUTE query
    LOOP
    END LOOP;

    l:= row.link;

    IF col THEN l = ST_collect(l);
    END IF;

    RETURN l;

END;
$$


LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE STRICT;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION connected_substring_as_geometry(tbl varchar, edge integer, next_edge integer, x double precision, y double precision)
    RETURNS GEOMETRY AS
$$
DECLARE
    row record;
    num integer;
    i integer;
    geom geoms;

    l geometry;
    l1 geometry;
    l2 geometry;
    pos double precision;

    cp geometry;

    pnt integer;

    srid integer;

    query text;

    cont boolean;

BEGIN

    FOR row IN EXECUTE 'select st_srid(the_geom) as srid from '||tbl||' where gid = (select min(gid) from '||tbl||')' LOOP
    END LOOP;
    srid:= row.srid;

--    FOR row in EXECUTE 'select * from intersection((select ST_linemerge(the_geom) from '||tbl||' where gid='||edge||'), '||
--          '(select ST_linemerge(the_geom) from '||tbl||' where gid='||next_edge||')) as cp'
--    LOOP
--    END LOOP;

    FOR row in EXECUTE 'select case when (select source from '||tbl||' where gid='||edge||')=(select source from '||tbl||
            ' where gid='||next_edge||') then (select ST_startpoint(the_geom) from '||tbl||' where gid='||next_edge||') when (select source from '
            ||tbl||' where gid='||edge||')=(select target from '||tbl||' where gid='||next_edge||') then (select ST_endpoint(the_geom) from '
            ||tbl||' where gid='||next_edge||')  when (select target from '||tbl||' where gid='||edge||')=(select source from '
            ||tbl||' where gid='||next_edge||') then (select ST_startpoint(the_geom) from '||tbl||
            ' where gid='||next_edge||') when (select target from '||tbl||' where gid='||edge||')=(select target from '||tbl||
            ' where gid='||next_edge||') then (select ST_endpoint(the_geom) from '||tbl||' where gid='||next_edge||') end as cp'

    LOOP
    END LOOP;

    cp:=row.cp;

    FOR row in EXECUTE 'select * from ST_line_locate_point((select ST_linemerge(the_geom) from '||tbl||' where gid='||edge||'), ST_geometryfromtext(''POINT('
                ||x||' '||y||')'', '||srid||')) as pos'
    LOOP
    END LOOP;

    pos:=row.pos;

--    FOR row IN EXECUTE 'select case when astext(ST_startpoint(the_geom)) = '''||astext(cp)||''' then 0 else 1 end as pnt from '||tbl||' where gid='||edge
--    LOOP
--    END LOOP;
--    
--    pnt=row.pnt;

    -- Creating new geometries

    FOR row in EXECUTE 'select * from ST_line_substring((select ST_linemerge(the_geom) from '||tbl||' where gid='||edge||'), 0, '||pos||') as link'
    LOOP
    END LOOP;

    l1:=row.link;

    FOR row in EXECUTE 'select * from ST_line_substring((select ST_linemerge(the_geom) from '||tbl||' where gid='||edge||'), '||pos||', 1) as link'
    LOOP
    END LOOP;

    l2:=row.link;


    IF cp=ST_startpoint(l1) OR cp=ST_endpoint(l1) THEN
    l:=l1;
    ELSE
    l:=l2;
    END IF;

    RETURN l;

END;
$$

LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE STRICT;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION shootingstar_sp_smart(
       geom_table varchar, source_x float8, source_y float8, target_x float8, target_y float8, delta float8, cost_column varchar, dir boolean, rc boolean) 
       RETURNS SETOF GEOMS AS
$$
DECLARE
r record;
g geoms;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN EXECUTE 'SELECT id, gid, the_geom from shootingstar_sp_smart('''||geom_table||''', '||source_x||', '||source_y||', '||target_x||
                   ', '||target_y||', '||delta||', '''||cost_column||''', ''reverse_cost'', ''to_cost'', '||text(dir)||', '||text(rc)||')'
  LOOP
    g.id := r.id;
    g.gid := r.gid;
    g.the_geom := r.the_geom;
    RETURN NEXT g;
  END LOOP;

END;
$$

LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE STRICT;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION shootingstar_sp_smart(
       geom_table varchar, source_x float8, source_y float8, target_x float8, target_y float8, delta float8, cost_column varchar, reverse_cost_column varchar, dir boolean, rc boolean) 
       RETURNS SETOF GEOMS AS
$$
DECLARE
r record;
g geoms;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN EXECUTE 'SELECT id, gid, the_geom from shootingstar_sp_smart('''||geom_table||''', '||source_x||', '||source_y||', '||target_x||
                   ', '||target_y||', '||delta||', '''||cost_column||''', '''||reverse_cost_column||''', ''to_cost'', '||text(dir)||', '||text(rc)||')'
  LOOP
    g.id := r.id;
    g.gid := r.gid;
    g.the_geom := r.the_geom;
    RETURN NEXT g;
  END LOOP;

END;
$$

LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE STRICT;
```

the rest is on the next answer(due to the limitation of answer characters!!!).

Answer (score 1):

the rest:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION shootingstar_sp_smart(
       geom_table varchar, source_x float8, source_y float8, target_x float8, target_y float8, delta float8, cost_column varchar, reverse_cost_column varchar, to_cost_column varchar, dir boolean, rc boolean) 
       RETURNS SETOF GEOMS AS
$$
DECLARE 
        rec record;
        r record;
        path_result record;
        v_id integer;
        e_id integer;
        geom geoms;

    intersection text;

        srid integer;

    s_gid integer;
    t_gid integer;

    max_gid integer;
    max_vertex_id integer;

    l_pair links;
    middle geometry;

        ll_x float8;
        ll_y float8;
        ur_x float8;
        ur_y float8;

        query text;
    i integer;

        id integer;

    seqname text;

    source edge;
    target edge;

    curr edge;
    tmp edge;

    extra_edges edge_array;
BEGIN

        id :=0;
        FOR rec IN EXECUTE
            'select ST_srid(the_geom) as srid from ' ||
            quote_ident(geom_table) || ' limit 1'
        LOOP
        END LOOP;
        srid := rec.srid;

    FOR rec IN EXECUTE 'SELECT CASE WHEN '||source_x||'<'||target_x||
           ' THEN '||source_x||' ELSE '||target_x||
           ' END as ll_x, CASE WHEN '||source_x||'>'||target_x||
           ' THEN '||source_x||' ELSE '||target_x||' END as ur_x'
        LOOP
        END LOOP;

        ll_x := rec.ll_x;
        ur_x := rec.ur_x;

        FOR rec IN EXECUTE 'SELECT CASE WHEN '||source_y||'<'||
            target_y||' THEN '||source_y||' ELSE '||
            target_y||' END as ll_y, CASE WHEN '||
            source_y||'>'||target_y||' THEN '||
            source_y||' ELSE '||target_y||' END as ur_y'
        LOOP
        END LOOP;

        ll_y := rec.ll_y;
        ur_y := rec.ur_y;

    -- Searching for the source and target edges
    SELECT find_nearest_link_within_distance_xy(source_x, source_y, delta, geom_table) INTO s_gid;
    SELECT find_nearest_link_within_distance_xy(target_x, target_y, delta, geom_table) INTO t_gid;

--        RAISE NOTICE 'SELECT gid,source,target,x1,y1,x2,y2,length,reverse_cost,id,class_id,to_cost::double precision,rule,the_geom FROM % WHERE gid = %', quote_ident(geom_table), s_gid;
--        RAISE NOTICE 'SELECT gid,source,target,x1,y1,x2,y2,length,reverse_cost,id,class_id,to_cost::double precision,rule,the_geom FROM % WHERE gid = %', quote_ident(geom_table), t_gid;

        FOR rec IN EXECUTE 'SELECT gid,source,target,x1,y1,x2,y2,'||cost_column||' as length, '||reverse_cost_column||' as reverse_cost,'||to_cost_column||'||''.0'' as to_cost,rule,the_geom FROM ' || quote_ident(geom_table) || ' WHERE gid = ' || s_gid
    LOOP
    END LOOP;

        source.gid          := rec.gid;
    source.target       := rec.target;
    source.source       := rec.source;
    source.x1           := rec.x1;
    source.y1           := rec.y1;
    source.x2           := rec.x2;
    source.y2           := rec.y2;
    source.length       := rec.length;
    source.reverse_cost := rec.reverse_cost;
--  source.id           := rec.id;
--  source.class_id     := rec.class_id;
    source.to_cost      := rec.to_cost;

--  RAISE NOTICE 'source.to_cost = %', source.to_cost::double precision;

    source.rule         := rec.rule;
    source.the_geom     := rec.the_geom;

        FOR rec IN EXECUTE 'SELECT gid,source,target,x1,y1,x2,y2,'||cost_column||' as length, '||reverse_cost_column||' as reverse_cost,'||to_cost_column||' as to_cost,rule,the_geom FROM ' || quote_ident(geom_table) || ' WHERE gid = ' || t_gid
    LOOP
    END LOOP;

        target.gid          := rec.gid;
    target.target       := rec.target;
    target.source       := rec.source;
    target.x1           := rec.x1;
    target.y1           := rec.y1;
    target.x2           := rec.x2;
    target.y2           := rec.y2;
    target.length       := rec.length;
    target.reverse_cost := rec.reverse_cost;
--  target.id           := rec.id;
--  target.class_id     := rec.class_id;
    target.to_cost      := rec.to_cost;
    target.rule         := rec.rule;
    target.the_geom     := rec.the_geom;

--        FOR rec IN EXECUTE 'SELECT max(gid) AS max_gid, greatest(max(source), max(target)) AS max_vertex_id FROM ' 
--    || quote_ident(geom_table) || ' where setSRID(''BOX3D('||
--          ll_x-delta||' '||ll_y-delta||','||ur_x+delta||' '||
--          ur_y+delta||')''::BOX3D, ' || srid || ') && the_geom'
--  LOOP
--  END LOOP;

        FOR rec IN EXECUTE 'SELECT max_gid, max_vertex_id FROM network_info WHERE tname = ''' || quote_ident(geom_table) || ''''
    LOOP
    END LOOP;

    max_gid:=rec.max_gid;
    max_vertex_id:=rec.max_vertex_id;

--  RAISE NOTICE 'max_gid=%, max_vertex_id=%', max_gid, max_vertex_id;

        -- Locate source and target points
    -- extra_edges[1] - source first
    -- extra_edges[2] - source last
        SELECT DISTINCT l, f FROM locate_point_as_geometry(geom_table, s_gid, source_x, source_y, false) INTO l_pair.l, l_pair.f;

    extra_edges.the_geom[1] := l_pair.f;
    extra_edges.gid[1] := max_gid+1;
    extra_edges.source[1] := source.source;
    -- New target vertex (max_vertex_id+1)
    extra_edges.target[1] := max_vertex_id+1;
    extra_edges.x1[1] := source.x1;
    extra_edges.y1[1] := source.y1;
    extra_edges.x2[1] := ST_x(pgr_startpoint(l_pair.f));
    extra_edges.y2[1] := ST_y(pgr_startpoint(l_pair.f));
--  extra_edges.x2[1] := x(PointN(l_pair.f, NumPoints(l_pair.f)));
--  extra_edges.y2[1] := y(PointN(l_pair.f, NumPoints(l_pair.f)));
    extra_edges.length[1] := source.length*(ST_length(l_pair.f)/ST_length(source.the_geom));
    extra_edges.reverse_cost[1] := source.reverse_cost*(ST_length(l_pair.f)/ST_length(source.the_geom));
--  extra_edges.id[1] := source.id;
--  extra_edges.class_id[1] := source.class_id;
--  extra_edges.to_cost[1] := source.to_cost;
    extra_edges.rule[1] := source.rule;
    --extra_edges[1]:=curr;

    extra_edges.the_geom[2] := l_pair.l;
    extra_edges.gid[2] := max_gid+2;
    extra_edges.target[2] := source.target;
    -- New target vertex (max_vertex_id+1)
    extra_edges.source[2] := max_vertex_id+1;
    extra_edges.x2[2] := source.x2;
    extra_edges.y2[2] := source.y2;
--  extra_edges.x1[2] := ST_x(ST_startpoint(l_pair.f));
--  extra_edges.y1[2] := ST_y(ST_startpoint(l_pair.f));
    extra_edges.x1[2] := ST_x(ST_pointn(l_pair.f, ST_NumPoints(l_pair.f)));
    extra_edges.y1[2] := ST_y(ST_pointn(l_pair.f, ST_NumPoints(l_pair.f)));
    extra_edges.length[2] := source.length*(ST_length(l_pair.l)/ST_length(source.the_geom));
    extra_edges.reverse_cost[2] := source.reverse_cost*(ST_length(l_pair.l)/ST_length(source.the_geom));
--  extra_edges.id[2] := source.id;
--  extra_edges.class_id[2] := source.class_id;
    extra_edges.to_cost[2] := source.to_cost;
    extra_edges.rule[2] := source.rule;
    --extra_edges[2]:=curr;

    -- extra_edges[3] - target first
    -- extra_edges[4] - target last
        SELECT DISTINCT l, f FROM locate_point_as_geometry(geom_table, t_gid, target_x, target_y, true) INTO l_pair.l, l_pair.f;
    extra_edges.the_geom[3] := l_pair.f;
    extra_edges.gid[3] := max_gid+3;
    extra_edges.source[3] := target.source;
    -- New target vertex (max_vertex_id+2)
    extra_edges.target[3] := max_vertex_id+2;
    extra_edges.x1[3] := target.x1;
    extra_edges.y1[3] := target.y1;
    extra_edges.x2[3] := ST_x(pgr_endpoint(l_pair.f));
    extra_edges.y2[3] := ST_y(pgr_endpoint(l_pair.f));
    extra_edges.length[3] := target.length*(ST_length(l_pair.f)/ST_length(target.the_geom));
    extra_edges.reverse_cost[3] := target.reverse_cost*(ST_length(l_pair.f)/ST_length(target.the_geom));
--  extra_edges.id[3] := target.id;
--  extra_edges.class_id[3] := target.class_id;
    extra_edges.to_cost[3] := target.to_cost;
    extra_edges.rule[3] := target.rule;
    --extra_edges[3]:=curr;

    extra_edges.the_geom[4] := l_pair.l;
    extra_edges.gid[4] := max_gid+4;
    extra_edges.target[4] := target.target;
    -- New target vertex (max_vertex_id+2)
    extra_edges.source[4] := max_vertex_id+2;
    extra_edges.x2[4] := target.x2;
    extra_edges.y2[4] := target.y2;
    extra_edges.x1[4] := ST_x(pgr_endpoint(l_pair.f));
    extra_edges.y1[4] := ST_y(pgr_endpoint(l_pair.f));
    extra_edges.length[4] := target.length*(ST_length(l_pair.l)/ST_length(target.the_geom));
    extra_edges.reverse_cost[4] := target.reverse_cost*(ST_length(l_pair.l)/ST_length(target.the_geom));
--  extra_edges.id[4] := target.id;
--  extra_edges.class_id[4] := target.class_id;
    extra_edges.to_cost[4] := target.to_cost;
    extra_edges.rule[4] := target.rule;
    --extra_edges[4]:=curr;

    -- extra_edges[5] - extra source edge
    -- extra_edges[6] - extra target edge

    --tmp := extra_edges[1];

    extra_edges.the_geom[5] := ST_geometryfromtext('MULTILINESTRING(('||source_x||' '||source_y||','||extra_edges.x1[2]||' '||extra_edges.y1[2]||'))', srid);

--  RAISE NOTICE 'source.rule = %', source.rule;

    extra_edges.gid[5] := max_gid+5;
    -- New target vertex (max_vertex_id+3)
    extra_edges.source[5] := max_vertex_id+3;
    extra_edges.target[5] := extra_edges.target[1];
    extra_edges.x1[5] := source_x;
    extra_edges.y1[5] := source_y;
    extra_edges.x2[5] := extra_edges.x2[2];
    extra_edges.y2[5] := extra_edges.y2[2];
    extra_edges.length[5] := ST_length(extra_edges.the_geom[5]);
    extra_edges.reverse_cost[5] := 1000000.0;
--  extra_edges.id[5] := 0;
--  extra_edges.class_id[5] := source.class_id;
--  RAISE NOTICE 'class_id[5] = %', extra_edges.class_id[5];
    extra_edges.to_cost[5] := NULL;--source.to_cost;
--  RAISE NOTICE 'to_cost[5] = %', extra_edges.to_cost[5];
    extra_edges.rule[5] := NULL;--source.rule;
--  RAISE NOTICE 'rule[5] = %', extra_edges.rule[5];
    --extra_edges[5]:=curr;

    --tmp := extra_edges[3];

    extra_edges.the_geom[6] := ST_geometryfromtext('MULTILINESTRING(('||extra_edges.x2[3]||' '||extra_edges.y2[3]||','||target_x||' '||target_y||'))', srid);

    extra_edges.gid[6] := max_gid+6;

--  RAISE NOTICE 'the_geom[6] = %', extra_edges.the_geom[6];

    -- New target vertex (max_vertex_id+4)
    extra_edges.source[6] := max_vertex_id+4;
    extra_edges.target[6] := extra_edges.target[3];
    extra_edges.x2[6] := target_x;
    extra_edges.y2[6] := target_y;
    extra_edges.x1[6] := extra_edges.x2[3];
    extra_edges.y1[6] := extra_edges.y2[3];
    extra_edges.length[6] := ST_length(extra_edges.the_geom[6]);
    extra_edges.reverse_cost[6] := 1000000.0;
--  extra_edges.id[6] := 0;
--  extra_edges.class_id[6] := target.class_id;
    extra_edges.to_cost[6] := target.to_cost;
    extra_edges.rule[6] := target.rule;
    --extra_edges[6]:=curr;

    select relname INTO seqname from pg_class where relname='rownum';

    IF seqname IS NOT NULL THEN
      PERFORM setval('rownum', 1, false);
    ELSE
      EXECUTE 'create sequence rownum';
    END IF;


        IF s_gid = t_gid THEN

      SELECT * FROM get_middle(geom_table, s_gid, source_x, source_y, target_x, target_y, true) INTO middle;

      geom.gid := extra_edges.gid[5];
          geom.the_geom := extra_edges.the_geom[5];
      geom.id := 0;    
          RETURN NEXT geom;

      geom.gid := extra_edges.gid[1];
          geom.the_geom := middle;
      geom.id := 1;
          RETURN NEXT geom;

      geom.gid := extra_edges.gid[6];
          geom.the_geom := extra_edges.the_geom[6];
      geom.id := 2;
          RETURN NEXT geom;

      RETURN;

    END IF;


        -- Shooting* search query
query := 'select distinct a.rownum as id, a.edge_id, b.gid, b.the_geom from (select nextval(''rownum'') as rownum, id2 as edge_id from ' || 
          'pgr_trsp(''SELECT gid as id, source::integer, ' || 
          'target::integer, '||cost_column||'::float8  as cost';




        IF rc THEN query := query || ' , '||reverse_cost_column||'::double precision as reverse_cost ';  
        END IF;

        query := query || ' FROM ' || quote_ident(geom_table) || ' where ST_setSRID(''''BOX3D('||
          ll_x-delta||' '||ll_y-delta||','||ur_x+delta||' '||
          ur_y+delta||')''''::BOX3D, ' || srid || ') && the_geom';

--  RAISE NOTICE 'Query: %', query;

    -- Newly created edges should be appended here
        FOR i IN 1..6 LOOP
      --curr := extra_edges[i];
--    RAISE NOTICE 'i=%', i;
      IF extra_edges.rule[i] IS NULL THEN extra_edges.rule[i]:='NULL';
      ELSE extra_edges.rule[i]:=''''''||extra_edges.rule[i]||'''''';
      END IF;
      IF extra_edges.to_cost[i] IS NULL THEN extra_edges.to_cost[i]:=0;
      END IF;

     --  query := query || ' UNION ALL SELECT ' || extra_edges.gid[i]::integer || ', ' || extra_edges.source[i]::integer ||
--             ', ' || extra_edges.target[i]::integer || ', ' || extra_edges.length[i]::double precision ||
--             ', ' || extra_edges.x1[i]::double precision || ', ' || extra_edges.y1[i]::double precision ||
--             ', ' || extra_edges.x2[i]::double precision || ', ' || extra_edges.y2[i]::double precision ||
--             ', ' || extra_edges.rule[i]::varchar || ', ' || extra_edges.to_cost[i]::double precision;
        query := query || ' UNION ALL SELECT ' || extra_edges.gid[i]::integer || ', ' || extra_edges.source[i]::integer ||
               ', ' || extra_edges.target[i]::integer || ', ' || extra_edges.length[i]::double precision ;
                   IF rc THEN query := query || ' , ' || extra_edges.reverse_cost[i]::double precision;
                   END IF;
--  RAISE NOTICE 'Query: %', query;
    END LOOP;

        -- Need to use new ids as source and target

      --curr := extra_edges[5];
      --tmp := extra_edges[6];

--  RAISE NOTICE 'Query: %', query;

--  query := query || ' ORDER BY id'', ' ||       
--           quote_literal(extra_edges.gid[5]) || ' , ' || 
--           quote_literal(extra_edges.gid[6]) || ' , '''||text(dir)||''', '''||text(rc)||''' ) ) a LEFT JOIN ' || 
--           quote_ident(geom_table) || ' b ON (a.edge_id=b.gid) ';
query := query || ' ORDER BY id'', ' ||       
          quote_literal(extra_edges.gid[5]) || ' , ' || 
          quote_literal(extra_edges.gid[6]) || ' , '''||text(dir)||''', '''||text(rc)||''' ) ) a LEFT JOIN ' || 
          quote_ident(geom_table) || ' b ON (a.edge_id=b.gid) ';


    --RAISE NOTICE 'max_gid: %, max_vertex_id: %', max_gid, max_vertex_id;
--  RAISE NOTICE 'Query: %', query;

        --geom.gid := extra_edges.gid[5];
        --geom.the_geom := extra_edges.the_geom[5];
    --geom.id := 0;

        --RETURN NEXT geom;

        FOR path_result IN EXECUTE query
        LOOP
                 geom.gid      := path_result.edge_id;
--           RAISE NOTICE ' -- gid: %', geom.gid;

         -- Need to search for new geometries in the array instead of the table
         IF geom.gid > max_gid THEN
           --curr := extra_edges[geom.gid-max_gid];
           geom.the_geom := extra_edges.the_geom[geom.gid-max_gid];
         ELSE
                   geom.the_geom := path_result.the_geom;
         END IF;

         id := id+1;
--                 geom.id       := id;
                 geom.id       := path_result.id;

                 RETURN NEXT geom;

        END LOOP;

        RETURN;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE STRICT; 


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_smart_directed(
       geom_table varchar, heuristic boolean, source_x float8, source_y float8, target_x float8, target_y float8, 
       delta float8, cost_column varchar, reverse_cost_column varchar, dir boolean, rc boolean) 
       RETURNS SETOF GEOMS AS
$$
DECLARE 
        rec record;
        r record;
        path_result record;
        v_id integer;
        e_id integer;
        geom geoms;

        srid integer;

    s_gid integer;
    t_gid integer;

    max_gid integer;
    max_vertex_id integer;

    l_pair links;
    middle geometry;

        ll_x float8;
        ll_y float8;
        ur_x float8;
        ur_y float8;

        query text;
    i integer;

    fname text;
    seqname text;

        id integer;

    source edge;
    target edge;

    curr edge;
    tmp edge;

    extra_edges edge_array;
BEGIN

        id :=0;

    -- IF heuristic THEN fname = 'shortest_path_astar';
--  ELSE fname = 'shortest_path';
--  END IF;
    IF heuristic THEN fname = 'pgr_astar';
    ELSE fname = 'pgr_dijkstra';
    END IF;

        FOR rec IN EXECUTE
            'select srid from geometry_columns where f_table_name= ''' ||
            quote_ident(geom_table)||''''
        LOOP
        END LOOP;
        srid := rec.srid;

--  RAISE NOTICE 'SRID is set';


    FOR rec IN EXECUTE 'SELECT CASE WHEN '||source_x||'<'||target_x||
           ' THEN '||source_x||' ELSE '||target_x||
           ' END as ll_x, CASE WHEN '||source_x||'>'||target_x||
           ' THEN '||source_x||' ELSE '||target_x||' END as ur_x'
        LOOP
        END LOOP;

        ll_x := rec.ll_x;
        ur_x := rec.ur_x;

        FOR rec IN EXECUTE 'SELECT CASE WHEN '||source_y||'<'||
            target_y||' THEN '||source_y||' ELSE '||
            target_y||' END as ll_y, CASE WHEN '||
            source_y||'>'||target_y||' THEN '||
            source_y||' ELSE '||target_y||' END as ur_y'
        LOOP
        END LOOP;

        ll_y := rec.ll_y;
        ur_y := rec.ur_y;

    -- Searching for the source and target edges

--  RAISE NOTICE 'Searching for the source and target edges';

    SELECT find_nearest_link_within_distance_xy(source_x, source_y, delta, geom_table) INTO s_gid;
    SELECT find_nearest_link_within_distance_xy(target_x, target_y, delta, geom_table) INTO t_gid;

--  RAISE NOTICE 'Nearest links were found';

        FOR rec IN EXECUTE 'SELECT DISTINCT gid,source,target,x1,y1,x2,y2,'||cost_column||' as length, '||reverse_cost_column||' as reverse_cost,the_geom FROM ' || quote_ident(geom_table) || ' WHERE gid = ' || s_gid
    LOOP
    END LOOP;

        source.gid          := rec.gid;
    source.target       := rec.target;
    source.source       := rec.source;
    source.x1           := rec.x1;
    source.y1           := rec.y1;
    source.x2           := rec.x2;
    source.y2           := rec.y2;
    source.length       := rec.length;
    source.reverse_cost := rec.reverse_cost;
    source.the_geom     := rec.the_geom;

        FOR rec IN EXECUTE 'SELECT DISTINCT gid,source,target,x1,y1,x2,y2,'||cost_column||' as length, '||reverse_cost_column||' as reverse_cost,the_geom FROM ' || quote_ident(geom_table) || ' WHERE gid = ' || t_gid
    LOOP
    END LOOP;

        target.gid          := rec.gid;
    target.target       := rec.target;
    target.source       := rec.source;
    target.x1           := rec.x1;
    target.y1           := rec.y1;
    target.x2           := rec.x2;
    target.y2           := rec.y2;
    target.length       := rec.length;
    target.reverse_cost := rec.reverse_cost;
    target.the_geom     := rec.the_geom;

--  RAISE NOTICE 'Searching for max gid and node id';

        FOR rec IN EXECUTE 'SELECT max_gid, max_vertex_id FROM network_info WHERE tname = ''' || quote_ident(geom_table) || ''''
    LOOP
    END LOOP;

    max_gid:=rec.max_gid;
    max_vertex_id:=rec.max_vertex_id;

--  RAISE NOTICE 'Max gid and node id were found';

        -- Locate source and target points
    -- extra_edges[1] - source first
    -- extra_edges[2] - source last
        SELECT DISTINCT l, f FROM locate_point_as_geometry(geom_table, s_gid, source_x, source_y, false) INTO l_pair.l, l_pair.f;

-- RAISE NOTICE 'Creating fake edges';

    extra_edges.the_geom[1] := l_pair.f;
    extra_edges.gid[1] := max_gid+1;
    extra_edges.source[1] := source.source;
    -- New target vertex (max_vertex_id+1)
    extra_edges.target[1] := max_vertex_id+1;
    extra_edges.x1[1] := source.x1;
    extra_edges.y1[1] := source.y1;
    extra_edges.x2[1] := ST_x(pgr_startpoint(l_pair.f));
    extra_edges.y2[1] := ST_y(pgr_startpoint(l_pair.f));
    extra_edges.length[1] := source.length*(ST_length(l_pair.f)/ST_length(source.the_geom));
    extra_edges.reverse_cost[1] := source.reverse_cost*(ST_length(l_pair.f)/ST_length(source.the_geom));

    extra_edges.the_geom[2] := l_pair.l;
    extra_edges.gid[2] := max_gid+2;
    extra_edges.target[2] := source.target;
    -- New target vertex (max_vertex_id+1)
    extra_edges.source[2] := max_vertex_id+1;
    extra_edges.x2[2] := source.x2;
    extra_edges.y2[2] := source.y2;
    extra_edges.x1[2] := ST_x(ST_pointN(l_pair.f, ST_NumPoints(l_pair.f)));
    extra_edges.y1[2] := ST_y(ST_pointN(l_pair.f, ST_NumPoints(l_pair.f)));
    extra_edges.length[2] := source.length*(ST_length(l_pair.l)/ST_length(source.the_geom));
    extra_edges.reverse_cost[2] := source.reverse_cost*(ST_length(l_pair.l)/ST_length(source.the_geom));

    -- extra_edges[3] - target first
    -- extra_edges[4] - target last
        SELECT DISTINCT l, f FROM locate_point_as_geometry(geom_table, t_gid, target_x, target_y, false) INTO l_pair.l, l_pair.f;
    extra_edges.the_geom[3] := l_pair.f;
    extra_edges.gid[3] := max_gid+3;
    extra_edges.source[3] := target.source;
    -- New target vertex (max_vertex_id+2)
    extra_edges.target[3] := max_vertex_id+2;
    extra_edges.x1[3] := target.x1;
    extra_edges.y1[3] := target.y1;
    extra_edges.x2[3] := ST_x(pgr_endpoint(l_pair.f));
    extra_edges.y2[3] := ST_y(pgr_endpoint(l_pair.f));
    extra_edges.length[3] := target.length*(ST_length(l_pair.f)/ST_length(target.the_geom));
    extra_edges.reverse_cost[3] := target.reverse_cost*(ST_length(l_pair.f)/ST_length(target.the_geom));

    extra_edges.the_geom[4] := l_pair.l;
    extra_edges.gid[4] := max_gid+4;
    extra_edges.target[4] := target.target;
    -- New target vertex (max_vertex_id+2)
    extra_edges.source[4] := max_vertex_id+2;
    extra_edges.x2[4] := target.x2;
    extra_edges.y2[4] := target.y2;
    extra_edges.x1[4] := ST_x(pgr_endpoint(l_pair.f));
    extra_edges.y1[4] := ST_y(pgr_endpoint(l_pair.f));
    extra_edges.length[4] := target.length*(ST_length(l_pair.l)/ST_length(target.the_geom));
    extra_edges.reverse_cost[4] := target.reverse_cost*(ST_length(l_pair.l)/ST_length(target.the_geom));

    extra_edges.the_geom[5] := ST_geometryfromtext('LINESTRING('||source_x||' '||source_y||','||extra_edges.x1[2]||' '||extra_edges.y1[2]||')', srid);

    extra_edges.gid[5] := max_gid+5;
    -- New target vertex (max_vertex_id+3)
    extra_edges.source[5] := max_vertex_id+3;
    extra_edges.target[5] := extra_edges.target[1];
    extra_edges.x1[5] := source_x;
    extra_edges.y1[5] := source_y;
    extra_edges.x2[5] := extra_edges.x2[2];
    extra_edges.y2[5] := extra_edges.y2[2];
    extra_edges.length[5] := ST_length(extra_edges.the_geom[5]);
    extra_edges.reverse_cost[5] := 1000000.0;

    extra_edges.the_geom[6] := ST_geometryfromtext('LINESTRING('||extra_edges.x2[3]||' '||extra_edges.y2[3]||','||target_x||' '||target_y||')', srid);

    extra_edges.gid[6] := max_gid+6;

    -- New target vertex (max_vertex_id+4)
    extra_edges.source[6] := max_vertex_id+4;
    extra_edges.target[6] := extra_edges.target[3];
    extra_edges.x2[6] := target_x;
    extra_edges.y2[6] := target_y;
    extra_edges.x1[6] := extra_edges.x2[3];
    extra_edges.y1[6] := extra_edges.y2[3];
    extra_edges.length[6] := ST_length(extra_edges.the_geom[6]);
    extra_edges.reverse_cost[6] := 1000000.0;

    select relname INTO seqname from pg_class where relname='rownum';

    IF seqname IS NOT NULL THEN
      PERFORM setval('rownum', 1, false);
    ELSE
      EXECUTE 'create sequence rownum';
    END IF;

        IF s_gid = t_gid THEN

      SELECT * FROM get_middle(geom_table, s_gid, source_x, source_y, target_x, target_y, true) INTO middle;

      geom.gid := extra_edges.gid[5];
          geom.the_geom := extra_edges.the_geom[5];
      geom.id := 0;    
          RETURN NEXT geom;

      geom.gid := extra_edges.gid[1];
          geom.the_geom := middle;
      geom.id := 1;
          RETURN NEXT geom;

      geom.gid := extra_edges.gid[6];
          geom.the_geom := extra_edges.the_geom[6];
      geom.id := 2;
          RETURN NEXT geom;

      RETURN;

    END IF;

        -- Main search query
    -- Need to search for new geometries in the array instead of the table
    query := 'select distinct a.rownum as id, a.edge_id, b.gid, b.the_geom from (select nextval(''rownum'') as rownum, id2 as edge_id from ' || 
          fname || '(''SELECT DISTINCT gid as id, source::integer, ' || 
          'target::integer, '||cost_column||'::double precision as cost, ' || 
          'x1::double precision, y1::double precision, x2::double ' ||
          'precision, y2::double precision ';

        IF rc THEN query := query || ' , '||reverse_cost_column||' as reverse_cost ';  
        END IF;

        query := query || 'FROM ' || quote_ident(geom_table) || ' where ST_setSRID(''''BOX3D('||
          ll_x-delta||' '||ll_y-delta||','||ur_x+delta||' '||
          ur_y+delta||')''''::BOX3D, ' || srid || ') && the_geom';

--  RAISE NOTICE 'Query: %', query;

    -- Newly created edges should be appended here
        FOR i IN 1..6 LOOP
      --curr := extra_edges[i];
--    RAISE NOTICE 'i=%', i;
      IF extra_edges.rule[i] IS NULL THEN extra_edges.rule[i]:='NULL';
      ELSE extra_edges.rule[i]:=''''''||extra_edges.rule[i]||'''''';
      END IF;

      query := query || ' UNION ALL SELECT ' || extra_edges.gid[i]::integer || ', ' || extra_edges.source[i]::integer ||
               ', ' || extra_edges.target[i]::integer || ', ' || extra_edges.length[i]::double precision ||
               ', ' || extra_edges.x1[i]::double precision || ', ' || extra_edges.y1[i]::double precision ||
               ', ' || extra_edges.x2[i]::double precision || ', ' || extra_edges.y2[i]::double precision;
                   IF rc THEN query := query || ' , ' || extra_edges.reverse_cost[i]::double precision;
                   END IF;
--  RAISE NOTICE 'Query: %', query;
    END LOOP;


--  RAISE NOTICE 'Query: %', query;

    query := query || ''', ' ||       
          quote_literal(extra_edges.source[5]) || ' , ' || 
          quote_literal(extra_edges.target[6]) || ' , '''||text(dir)||''', '''||text(rc)||''' ) ) a LEFT JOIN ' || 
          quote_ident(geom_table) || ' b ON (a.edge_id=b.gid) ';

    --RAISE NOTICE 'max_gid: %, max_vertex_id: %', max_gid, max_vertex_id;
--  RAISE NOTICE 'Query: %', query;

        --RETURN NEXT geom;

        FOR path_result IN EXECUTE query
        LOOP
                 geom.gid      := path_result.edge_id;
--           RAISE NOTICE ' -- gid: %', geom.gid;

         -- Need to search for new geometries in the array instead of the table
         IF geom.gid > max_gid THEN
           geom.the_geom := extra_edges.the_geom[geom.gid-max_gid];
         ELSE
                   geom.the_geom := path_result.the_geom;
         END IF;

         id := id+1;
                 geom.id       := path_result.id;

                 RETURN NEXT geom;

        END LOOP;

        RETURN;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE STRICT;
```

Enjoy it!